# Carbohydrate in egg white

Tags: nutrition, carbohydrates, sugar

I looked up online to find which type of carbohydrate is found in egg white, but the only information I found is the quantity of sugar. I would like to know the exact name of the carbohydrate found in the egg white in order to draw the sugar molecule.

Comment: It's all in a glycosylated protein (as noted in the answer), the composition of which is not homogeneous. But I found: "MALDI MS of the N-glycans released from α-ovomucin by PNGase F revealed that the most abundant glycan structure is a bisected type of composition GlcNAc(6)Man(3)." (http://www.uniprot.org/citations/21484392)

Answer (score 2):

The one I found is Ovomucin,though it's not a pure carbohydrate.

> Ovomucin is a highly glycosylated protein and approximately 33% of ovomucin is made up of carbohydrates.

<sub>Nutritional Values of Egg White Proteins paragraph of
http://ps.oxfordjournals.org/content/92/12/3292.full</sub>

So you can see it's mostly a protein.

> Ovomucin is a trypsin inhibitor found in raw egg white.
>
> Ovomucin is responsible for the gel properties of fresh egg white and is believed to be involved in egg white thinning. Ovomucin is composed of two subunits:
>
> 1. α-ovomucin - carbohydrate-poor with a molecular mass of 254kDa
> 2. β-ovomucin - carbohydrate-rich with a molecular mass of 400-610kDa

<sub>Souce: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovomucin)</sub>

Comment: I'll add more info as soon as I find some.

Comment: I did some research about the ovomucin but I didn't found it molecular stucture... Have you any idea about the ccomposition of the sugar?

Comment: No sorry about that.